# Different notification tones for multiple Gmail accounts

Tags: gmail, notifications

Is it possible to use different notification tones for each Gmail account?  I.e.:

account1@gmail.com => tone X
account2@gmail.com => tone Y

Maybe with a helper app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GMail app already appears to do this on a per-account basis. Simply open an account, then navigate to `(Menu button)->More->Settings->Select Ringtone`. This works fine on my version (2.3.4.1) and allows me to set a different ringtone for each account.

You can also use this to cause some accounts to provide vibrate/audible notifications while others do not. For example, my work account is set to vibrate "for all notifications", but my other accounts have their vibration set to "Never".